# ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [manageDoctors] not defined. (View:

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am having

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('manageDoctors') }}">
         <i class="demo-psi-split-vertical-2"></i>
         <span class="menu-title">
         <strong>Manage Doctors</strong>
         </span>
         <!--       <i class="arrow"></i> -->
     </a>
</li>
```

in my view and

```
Route::post('login', 
            array('uses' => 'login\LoginController@doLogin'));
```

in my web.php.

and still getting error `Route [manageDoctors] not defined`.

I am new in Laravel

Comment: Please review your question and check the format! there is something wrong with it!

Comment: you have to add a route **named** 'manageDoctors' before you can call `route ('manageDoctors')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Route::post('login', 
        array('uses' => 'login\LoginController@doLogin'))->name('manageDoctors');
```

you have to name the routes specifically in your web file

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory, you have not defined any route called `manageDoctors`. You can:

```
Route::post('login', 
        array('uses' => 'login\LoginController@doLogin')); 
Route::get('manageDoctors', function () { 
     return response("Look, I'm managing doctors!");
});
```